# RMagick error installing Redmine on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, redmine, rmagick

I'm trying to upgrade my Redmine installation to the latest.
I updated ruby, rails, and gem as required.

```
current trunk  |  ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, jruby-1.6.7  |  Rails 3.2.6   |  RubyGems <= 1.8
```

Issuing the `rake db:migrate` command it gives me the following error:

> C:\ruby-apps\RedMine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
>   ←[31mCould not find gem 'rmagick (>= 2.0.0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.←[0m
>   ←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

So I installed rmagick for win32 and listing installed gems I see :

> ...
>   railties (3.2.6)
>   rake (0.9.2.2)
>   rdoc (3.12)
>   rmagick (2.12.0 mswin32)
>   ruby-openid (2.1.8)
>   rubygems-update (1.8.24)
>   ...

But `rake db:migrate` still give me the same error, so I tried `bundle install`, but I get:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
>          ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> ```
>
> checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
>   checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.

Any ideas on how to get out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [Bitnami's Redmine windows Installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer) contains a solution to this problem.
Using it, for me is a valid solution to the problem.

The content of the installation may be used to inspect correct versions and dependencies to correctly build Redmine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem while installing redmine. According to a comment in the Gemfile rmagick optional and only used to export Gant graphs as PNGs. So if you do not need this specific feature you can run

```
bundle install --without development test rmagick
```